# why if(a==2.3) evaluates false when float a=2.3

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float a = 2.3;
    if(a == 2.3) {
        pritnf("hello");
    }
    else {
        printf("hi");
    }
}
```

It prints "hi" in output, or we can say that if condition is getting false value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float a = 2.5;
    if(a == 2.5)
        printf("Hello");
    else
        printf("Hi");
}
```

It prints hello.

Comment: @dbush I disagree with this dupe. The supposed dupe is about floating-point *computation* being potentially inexact, while this question is about `float` versus `double` constants. The same problem would occur if `a` was a `short` or `char` that could not represent an integer constant.

Comment: So why is it happening??

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ (and that URL is important enough to be remembered)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variable `a` is a `float` that holds some value close to the mathematical value 2.3.

The literal `2.3` is a `double` that also holds some value close to the mathematical value 2.3, but because `double` has greater precision than `float`, this may be a different value from the value of `a`. Both `float` and `double` can only represent a finite number of values, so there are necessarily mathematical real numbers that cannot be represented exactly by either of those two types.

In the comparison `a == 2.3`, the left operand is promoted from `float` to `double`. This promotion is exact and preserves the value (as all promotions do), but as discussed above, that value may be a different one from that of the `2.3` literal.

To make a comparison between floats, you can use an appropriate float literal:

```
assert(a == 2.3f);
//             ^
```

Comment: in case of 2.5 it calculates it true?? Is it compiler specific??

Comment: Can you cite the part of the ISO C standard which guarantees this behavior? (I know there is one.)

Comment: Or rather ... don't use `==` for floating point values.

Comment: @Hariom: Yes, because for 2.5, both `float` and `double` happen to hold the exact same value. But that's essentially accidental. (It's because of the particular representation details of the types matching the particularly simple structure of 2.5, namely as a short, dense binary.)

Comment: I'd probably also write `float a = 2.3f;`, since this should guarantee equality.

Comment: correct but more helpful if mention that `==` is not a good idea with `floats`

Comment: @pmg: I think that's overly FUDdy. You can use equality comparison if you know what it means and what you're doing. The OP's situation is blatantly solvable (e.g. with `a == 2.3f`), and I wouldn't call it bad. The important point is not to assume exact *computations*.

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: See my previous comment. I don't agree with such an overly general statement. I prefer understanding over blind adherence to dogma.

Comment: @Diti: C11 6.2.5, "Types", says that the set of values representable by `float` is a subset of the values representable by `double`, and 6.3.1.5 on Conversions says that if a value can be represented exactly, the resulting value is that value. (C doesn't actually use the term "promotion" for floating point values, but C++ does.)

Answer (score 3):

`2.3` with binary representation is `01000000000100110011001100110011...`
so you are not able to set a float exactly to `2.3`
with double precision you get something similar: `2.299999952316284`

you converted a double to float when you wrote:

```
float a = 2.3;
```

the if checks if the `float a` is equal to `double 2.299999952316284`

you should write:

```
float a = 2.3f;
```

and you can check:

```
if (a == 2.3f) {
    ...
}
```

i would rather test with:

```
if (fabs(a - 2.3f) < 0.00001) {
    ...
}
```

the `2.5` represented with bits is: `01000000001000000000000000000000`

**EDIT:** `fabs` is part of the `<math.h>` or `<cmath>`

> Read this: [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: An implementation that uses decimal floats could certainly represent both 2.3 and 2.5 exactly. This is ultimately implementation-defined. The important point is that *some* values cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: no 2.3 will require infinite number of bits. C language never used decimal representation of floats, when you print the 2.3 it will show you a rounded number.

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: C11 draft standard n1570: *5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h> 1
The characteristics of floating types are defined in terms of a model that describes a
representation of floating-point numbers and values that provide information about an
implementation’s floating-point arithmetic. 21) The following parameters are used to
define the model for each floating-point type: [...] b base or radix of exponent representation (an integer > 1)* No requirement for `b` to be unequal to `10`.

Comment: interesting, i thought the values will be converted to [IEEE_floating_points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: C was developed in the very late 60's and early 70's. The IEEE 754 binary floating-point standard was established 1985. How would you expect C to require IEEE 754?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing floating point values is not as easy as it might seem, have a look at [Most effective way for float and double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).

It all boils down to the fact, that floating point numbers are not exact (well 
most are not). Usually you compare 2 floats by allowing a small error window (epsilon):

```
if( fabs(a - 2.3f) < epsion) { ... }
```

where epsilon is small enough for your calculation, but not too small (bigger than [Machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)).